# PHP if: finds date of jun, but not aug

Tags: php

This is so strange, must be a typo i cannot find!

First i get data from mySql and place it in a php array.
Then i do a var dump to see what i got:

```
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

I now se result:

```
[5341]=> array(2) {
    ["datum"]=> string(19) "2015-07-04 06:47:50"
    ["usag"]=> string(3) "avf"
}
[5342]=> array(2) {
    ["datum"]=> string(19) "2015-08-03 13:42:15"
    ["usag"]=> string(3) "avf"
}
```

So, i got result from both month 07 & 08!
Now i'd like to loop threw all results and place it in a arranged array.
I'd like it to be by year, and by month, and simply count the result.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    //Check if thisYear
    if(substr($row['datum'], 0, 4) == $thisYear){
        //Check if Jan
        if(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 01){ 
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['jan']++;
        }
        //Check if Feb
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 02){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['feb']++;
        }
        //Check if Mar
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 03){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['mar']++;
        }
        //Check if Apr
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 04){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['apr']++;
        }
        //Check if Maj
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 05){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['maj']++;
        }
        //Check if Jun
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 06){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['jun']++;
        }
        //Check if Jul
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 07){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['jul']++;
        }
        //Check if Aug
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 08){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['aug']++;
        }
        //Check if Sep
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 09){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['sep']++;
        }
        //Check if Okt
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 10){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['okt']++;
        }
        //Check if Nov
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 11){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['nov']++;
        }
        //Check if Dec
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 12){
            $totalElementCount[$thisYear]['dec']++;
        }
    }//if thisYear

    //Check if prevYear
    elseif(substr($row['datum'], 0, 4) == $prevYear){
        //Check if Jan
        if(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 01){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['jan']++;
        }
        //Check if Feb
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 02){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['feb']++;
        }
        //Check if Mar
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 03){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['mar']++;
        }
        //Check if Apr
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 04){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['apr']++;
        }
        //Check if Maj
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 05){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['maj']++;
        }
        //Check if Jun
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 06){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['jun']++;
        }
        //Check if Jul
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 07){ 
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['jul']++;
        }
        //Check if Aug
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 08){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['aug']++;
        }
        //Check if Sep
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 09){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['sep']++;
        }
        //Check if Okt
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 10){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['okt']++;
        }
        //Check if Nov
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 11){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['nov']++;
        }
        //Check if Dec
        elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 12){
            $totalElementCount[$prevYear]['dec']++;
        }
    }//if prevYear
} //while
```

When loop is finnished i do another: `var_dump($totalElementCount);` to se if the code works correct. But somehow 2015-08 & 2015-09 is missing!
WHY?

```
array(2) {
  [2015]=>
  array(10) {
   ["jan"]=>
       int(240)
   ["feb"]=>
       int(821)
   ["mar"]=>
       int(1190)
   ["apr"]=>
       int(1046)
   ["maj"]=>
      int(892)
   ["jun"]=>
      int(1036)
   ["jul"]=>
      int(117)
   ["okt"]=>
      int(1246)
   ["nov"]=>
      int(1035)
   ["dec"]=>
      int(697)
}
```

Comment: Dear me.... use something like `$totalElementCount[$thisYear][strtolower(date('M', (strtotime($row['datum'])))]` to eliminate all those `if` tests for every single month

Comment: And your issue is `08` and `09` in your comparisons.... numbers (if you were comparing stringwise instead using `'08'` and `'09'` would be ok) with a leading `0` are __octal__, and `08` and `09` are invalid octal values, and treated as `0`

Comment: @MarkBaker I know there must be a better way, like a for loop. But thats above my nowledge :D You are welcome to show me a better way :)

Comment: @MarkBaker Interesting. But how come, it works for all numbers, but not "08" & "09" ?

Comment: @MarkBaker It worked perfect by adding quotes. Thank you! Please write it down as an answear!

Comment: @Mjukis Because the octal system reaches from 0 to 7. 08 equals 0, 09 equals 1. 10 has no leading 0 and is interpreted as decimal number

Comment: `01` is octal `1`, which is the same as decimal `1`; `02` is octal `2` which is the same as decimal `2`; `07` is octal `7` which is the same as decimal `7`; `08` is saying it's octal, but it's an invalid octal number and is treated as `0`; `09` is saying it's octal, but it's an invalid octal number and is treated as `0`; `10` is decimal `10`, (no leading `0`, so not treated as octal), `11` is decimal `11`, (no leading `0`, so not treated as octal); `2` is decimal `12`, (no leading `0`, so not treated as octal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short and easy method to solve your problem is the following

1. Iterate through the results of your query
2. Don't use millions of elseif/if conditions. Go for switch/case if necessary. In this case no if condition is needed because you can parse the month by using `date()`.
3. Parse your date instead of comparing it. Your current code compare the month to the *octal number* with a leading 0 instead of the *decimal one*.

   ```
   while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
       $year = substr($row['datum'],0,4); //Define year of the data record
       $month = strtolower(date('M', (strtotime($date)))); //parse month to 3 letter short form, e.g. "jan"
       $totalElementCount[$year][$month]++; //increment totalElemCount of the defined year and month
   }
   ```

If you want to stick to your code (which is hard to maintain and not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)), just add quotes around every number you compare your date with, so you make a string comparison.

```
elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == 02){
```

to

```
elseif(substr($row['datum'], 5, 2) == "02"){
```